# Two periods between the last author name and year

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, harvard-style

I use `makebst` to create a `.bst` file, but there are two periods between the last author name and year. How can I remove one period?

[image]

The whole `myHarvard.bst` can be find [here](https://pastebin.com/mTtVeSt3). The following are two functions that I think are related.

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check

      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.url output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ". " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us the complete `.bst` file? If it's too large you can post it at pastebin or some other site like that.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your interest. The full `bst` file is attached in the question now.

Answer (score 2):

I think I find a way to sort it out.

[image]

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { add.period$ " " * write$ }    % <- change this line
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```